# I want to know exact command of "find . -name '*.c' -or -name '*.cpp'" in Linux

Tags: linux, find, command

I'm studying shell in Linux these days. and I've had one question.

Please, look at below command:

```
$ find . -name '*.c' -or -name '*.cpp'
```

Above command is processed like below command internally?

```
$ find . -name '*.c' -and -print -or -name '*.cpp' -and -print
```

Comment: Read [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) perhaps by typing `man find` and read the man page of every command before using it. Some few commands are builtin, e.g. `cd`. So read also the documentation of your shell, e.g. [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man find` says:

```
   If the whole expression contains no actions other than -prune or -print,
   -print is performed on all files for which the whole expression is true.
```

So yes, it's equivalent, but it's probably easier to think of it as:

```
find . \( -name '*.c' -or -name '*.cpp' \) -and -print
```

or simpler, and POSIX-compliant:

```
find . \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -print
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically both commands means same and display same output. Why to do with longer when you have shorter way?

Comment: @roaima this look like a comment to me, and I flag as such.

Answer (score 0):

The OR and AND operators follow Boolean logic.

For primitives A = `-name '*.c'`, B = `-name '*.cpp'`, C = `-print` we have the following equations

Your first example: (A+B).C

Your second example: (A.C)+(B.C)

These have a straightforward mathematical equivalence, ie they are the same. But the first is shorter and more succinct.